# Using zxing in Blackberry 5.0

Tags: blackberry, barcode, zxing

I'm stucked when implementing Barcode scanning in Blackberry 5.0 SDK, since I'm look into deep search on the internet, and found no clue.

Then I started to write my own class to provide Barcode Scanning (using zxing core)
then I need to implements BitmapLuminanceSource (rim version not Android version)

```
 public class BitmapLuminanceSource extends LuminanceSource {

    private final Bitmap bitmap;

    public BitmapLuminanceSource(Bitmap bitmap){
        super(bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
    }

    public byte[] getRow(int y, byte[] row) {
                //how to implement this method
        return null;
    }

    public byte[] getMatrix() {
                //how to implement this method
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem.

Here's the BitmapLuminanceSource implementation

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;

import com.google.zxing.LuminanceSource;

public class BitmapLuminanceSource extends LuminanceSource {

private final Bitmap bitmap;
private byte[] matrix;

public BitmapLuminanceSource(Bitmap bitmap) {
    super(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    this.bitmap = bitmap;

    int area = width * height;
    matrix = new byte[area];
    int[] rgb = new int[area];

    bitmap.getARGB(rgb, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int pixel = rgb[offset + x];
            int luminance = (306 * ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF) + 601
                    * ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF) + 117 * (pixel & 0xFF)) >> 10;
            matrix[offset + x] = (byte) luminance;
        }
    }

    rgb = null;

}

public byte[] getRow(int y, byte[] row) {
    if (y < 0 || y >= getHeight()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Requested row is outside the image: " + y);
    }

    int width = getWidth();
    if (row == null || row.length < width) {
        row = new byte[width];
    }

    int offset = y * width;
    System.arraycopy(this.matrix, offset, row, 0, width);

    return row;
}

public byte[] getMatrix() {
    return matrix;
}

}
```

I added com.google.zxing (library for Barcode encode/decode) to my project

Answer (score 1):

Well, the [javadoc](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/LuminanceSource.java) in `LuminanceSource` tells you what it returns. And you have implementations like `PlanarYUVLuminanceSource` in `android/` that show you an example of it in action. Did you look at these at all?

The quick answer though is that both return one row of the image, or the entire image, as an array of luminance values. There is one `byte` value per pixel and it should be treated as an unsigned value.

Comment: Yes. I have look at those. Then I had implement the BitmapLuminanceSource. When I run the project, it's not error. But I can't get the right values for the raw data. 

I'm encoding "Hello" to QR Code, but when want to decode
it returns unwanted characters (not "Hello")

I'm still need to validating is my BitmapLuminanceSource is implemented well. But thanks for the answer, I will give an update, once I've solved my problem.